# Accessing the source code of Stata commands and functions

Tags: stata

Is it possible to view the source code of Stata commands and functions? I am wondering how the `lnskew0` command is implemented in Stata.

The source code could help to adapt functions to other languages, such as Python and R:

[How to use Zero-skewness log transform in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390864/how-to-use-zero-skewness-log-transform-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions you can only see the inner workings of those relating to the `egen` command.

However, you can see the source code of commands/programs using the `viewsource` command:

```
viewsource lnskew0.ado
```

Typing `help viewsource` will provide further details.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :) And true, I didn't get the terminology right. Sorry, but I'm not too familiar with Stata. Thanks for clarifying ;)

Comment: Note that the source of commands with pre-compiled code cannot be accessed.